# Matlab - Interpolation over a 3D surf with matrix, nonuniform, scattered data

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, interpolation

I am currently trying to interpolate the following surface plot in order to add more point and make it more smooth:

hSurf = surf(X,Y,Z)

with X,Y and Z all being matrices of size nXm.

When looking for a solution, I have found the function griddata but I have found only a syntax with X,Y and Z as vectors. Therefore any attempts did not succeed!

Do you have an idea? Thx a lot!

Kooglof

Comment: There exists a function `interp2` for interpolating such kind of data. Just define your target grid with `griddata` and use `interp2`.

Comment: Thx. But my data set doesn't meet the requirements of *interp2* of a uniform mesh in both directions. I tried *TriScatteredInterp* but it doesn't accept matrices as input, only vectors.

Comment: I think when `surf` accepts the data, `interp2` should also. Can you provide a small numerical example? Maybe the first three rows and colums of `X`, `Y` and `Z`?

Comment: Then I do really know then since I got an error. Here is a minimal example of the numerical data:

X=[-0.2230   -0.2275   -0.2319;   -0.2196   -0.2240   -0.2284;   -0.2161   -0.2204   -0.2248];
Y=[0.2161    0.2204    0.2248;    0.2196    0.2240    0.2284;    0.2230    0.2275    0.2319];
Z=[0.0675    0.1048    0.1302;    0.0854    0.1174    0.1360;    0.1006    0.1275    0.1352];

figure(1)
surf(X,Y,Z)

It might look uniform here but on a long-scale, it is not.

Comment: See my answer below and forget my earlier comment, that `surf` only accepts regular grids.

Comment: Maybe you can achieve your goal by typing ``shading interp`` after the ``surf()`` command. It then interpolates the colors between your nodes without creating new nodes, i.e. data, which you do not really have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `griddata` was the correct approach. First, define a regular grid using `meshgrid`, e.g.

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-0.2160:-0.0001:-0.2319,0.2161:0.0001:0.2319); % replace the values by meaningful borders
```

and then map the nonregular grid `X`, `Y` to the regular grid

```
z = griddata(X,Y,Z,x,y,'cubic')
```

where `'cubic'` can be replaced by the preffered method.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `griddata` parameter to `natural`, `cubic` or `v4`. This will do interpolation and make your graph with non-uniform data smooth
Below is a sample MATLAb code

```py
x=[32 20 67 1 98 34 57 65 24 82 47 55 8 51 13 14 18 30 37 39 10 33 21 26 38 81 83 60 95 22 17 5 72 46 99 52 12 25 96 29 70 85 43 69 19 78 97 31 89 53 2 91 48 71 61 15 36 84 94 50 11 80 6 7 49 74 9 88 40 79 27 68 73 64 63 59 86 23 35 58 45 28 100 42 93 87 16 90 41 66 54 92 77 4 62 76 75 56 3 44];
y=[96 75 24 9 83 49 27 77 3 23 17 31 40 13 7 52 51 21 98 47 64 79 78 91 44 16 15 100 84 99 63 68 70 30 54 76 97 73 33 5 88 8 71 66 62 25 60 42 72 45 18 11 28 59 89 65 10 55 69 81 12 26 20 95 87 41 74 50 93 22 43 90 14 34 82 35 56 38 80 32 1 57 6 36 37 61 29 58 2 48 4 46 67 53 92 86 94 19 39 85];
z=[55 31 11 45 83 36 86 49 15 57 42 46 8 94 88 47 54 81 98 41 32 35 56 85 9 89 37 60 23 62 67 100 78 76 73 80 10 20 68 34 77 93 1 63 53 12 22 99 91 40 84 24 33 3 43 19 92 97 6 82 64 25 26 79 95 4 44 58 5 21 70 29 65 87 96 90 51 14 18 2 72 28 71 39 52 7 27 59 50 61 48 30 66 69 17 13 74 16 75 38];

xlin = linspace(min(x), max(x), 100);
ylin = linspace(min(y), max(y), 100);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(xlin, ylin);
% Z = griddata(x,y,z,X,Y,'natural');
% Z = griddata(x,y,z,X,Y,'cubic');
Z = griddata(x,y,z,X,Y,'v4');
mesh(X,Y,Z)
axis tight; hold on
plot3(x,y,z,'.','MarkerSize',15)
```

[image]